# string.length() stops after first word

Tags: c++, string, cin

I'm trying to find out the length of a string. This works and outputs `14`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
     string str = "this is sparta";
     cout << str.length() << endl;
}
```

However this fails:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
     string str;
     cin >> str;
     cout << str.length() << endl;
}
```

When I type in the sentence `this is sparta` and hit return I get `4` as length.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't type your code from memory. Copy and paste if from your editor. This is not your real code, because this code would not compile.

Comment: Try `getline(cin,str);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `cin` stops at whitespace. If you want to read all your words, you'll need to loop:

```
int main() {
    string str;
    while (cin >> str) {
        cout << str << " --> " << str.length() << endl;
    }
}
```

Or if you want them all at once, you'll need to use `getline`:

```
int main() {
    string str;
    while (getline(cin, str)) {
        cout << str << " --> " << str.length() << endl;
    }
}
```